# How to search hierarchically through code and text files?

Tags: python, search, text, grep, hierarchical-data

I am looking to search for a collection of words (through a git repo) where the words might not appear in the same line, but spread over several different lines. But the lines they are spread over is "hierarchical".

What do I mean by hierarchical? Consider a class hierarchy e.g.

```
class Alpha {
...
  function bar(cats, dogs) {
...
    print(elephants)
...
class Gamma {
...
  function bar(cats, dogs) {
...
    print(elephants)
...
```

I want to search for "print bar alpha" or "print bar gamma". The idea is that print is nested inside bar which in turn is nested inside Alpha.

I have written a simple python script that does it just by going through each line and keeping track of what has been found in the hierarchy so far. But I would like a fast solution. Searching for hundreds of files brings the python program to a very slow pace!

Other nice-to-haves:

- Ideally, the order of search terms would not matter. So, even if I search for "print alpha bar", will would give me back the first print line.
- I would like to define the hierarchy in a language specific manner. In a object oriented language, it would be defined like above. In an org-file, it is nesting of headings. In a text file, it might just be the indentation (as in python file).

Comment: Show the script you've written so others can suggest improvements/point out errors. It's highly unlikely that someone's gonna go out of their way and write a program from scratch for just a couple upvotes

Comment: @oguzismail: I was not looking for someone to write a program for me. I am glad you pointed out that how my request could be interpreted. I will put the script on github/gitlab after cleaning it up. What I was asking for was if there is a software/program I am missing I can use? For example, can I do some sort of grep/agrep/ag/awk trick to solve this? Some pointers, not the actual code, of course.

Comment: Hmmm... I noticed that the title of this page started with `python - `. Did I post this by mistake on python subgroup of stack overflow? I don't think so, but I might have by mistake. If anything, this is a question about unix!